# Why is filtering with multiple conditions not working?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I need to filter my DataFrame based on two conditions.  I need to filter out any observation where cause = 'fire' AND the flag = 1.  It can be fire and flag = 0.  It can be flag = 1 and cause != 'fire'.  Just not both at the same time.

I tried the following:

```
 df.loc[(df['flag'] != 1) & (df['cause'] != 'Fire')]
```

But this gets rid of all 1s and/or fire. I need both conditions to be met to be filtered out.  Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

built a DF with contents you defined.   Make sure you code your logic.  You state NOT(cause=="Fire" AND flag==1)

```
import random
c = ["Fire","Water"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"flag":[random.randint(0,1) for r in range(10)], "cause":[c[random.randint(0,1)] for r in range(10)]})

df.loc[~((df['flag'] == 1) & (df['cause'] == 'Fire'))]
```

Comment: But that filters out Fire with '0' for the flag.

Comment: updated - just code the logic you state and it works